# Validate XML by its correct XSD version

Tags: xml, xsd, versioning

we are dealing with several XSD's and XML files for different versions. We want to make sure that a xml file can be validated with its correct XSD. Is there a way to do it? So far I've come to this conclusions:

- You can versioning the xsd by setting the "version" attribute within the root element of the schema (easy :) )
- To do the same for the xml you can either put it in the comment section or in an attribute in the root element (both would require preprocessing when importing and after processing after export to write the version) - very nasty ;-)

I should also mention that we can't make sure the xml we get is correct to any XSD, because it can be passed by a third party.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you want to have a kind of mapping between XSD and XML files isn't it?

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind' no, not a mapping, a validation. Basically I want to know if a xml is valid against a certain xsd, but I have to figure out the xsd (version) I want to validate against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a version number on the root element, and then use an XProc pipeline to control the validation, where the XProc pipeline decides which schema to validate against based on what it sees in the version number.

Comment: sounds reasonable, I will try to do it that way, thanks for now

Comment: What's "an XProc pipeline"?

Comment: @DanMan the only answer I can give that fits in a StackOverflow comment box is: try google.

Comment: @DerApe so did you try XProc pipeline or something else? I have the exact same problem. Can you share you solution/experience please?

Comment: @happy_coder It's quite some time since then and unfortunately I can not look it up, I'm not working on that project anymore

Comment: @DerApe I understand! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**To avoid preprocessing**, any solution would be a variant of these two: assign unique namespaces per version, or consume your xml using different application endpoints per version (e.g URLs).